# VS Code に拡張機能の Vetur を入れても vue.js のシンタックスハイライトが有効にならない

Tags: html, vue.js, vscode

vue.jsの学習をしております。VS Codeの拡張機能にVeturを入れたのですが、シンタックスハイライトがされません。環境はUbuntu Mate 19.10です。

VSIX（0.23.0）から直接インストールしても結果は変わりませんでした。
どうすればシンタックスハイライトがされるのかご教授願います。

[veturの最新リリース](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/releases)

下記はソースファイルとなります。

**practice.vue**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  date: {

  }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<div id="app">
  <p>OK!</p>
</div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="practice.vue"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 提示されているソースはいずれも拡張子.vueのSFCではないようにみえます……(もし，1つめのファイルが`practice.vue`であるというならば，その拡張子は.jsが適切でしょう)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローはチャットではないため、時間に関する挨拶 (おはよう、こんばんは等) はリアルタイムに読まれるとは限らないことを考えると省略しても特に失礼とはなりません。

Comment: なるほど、ファイル名が無いなと思っていたのですが、コードブロックの ``` の右に書かれていたのですね。ここはソースコードのハイライトを示すために使われる場所なので、今回の場合は `html` などと書くのが良いです。cubick さん編集ありがとうございます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu コードブロックの ``` 横に「ファイル名」や「コードの1行目」、もしくは言語を指定してるけど大文字を使ってしまっているケースは結構見かけます。

Comment: @hinaloe 拡張子は.jsが適切なのですね！ありがとうございます！早速試してみます(^^)

Comment: @cubick そうなのですね！では、今後は省略させていただきます。教えていただき感謝です♫コードブロックの```の横はファイル名ではなく拡張子だけでいいのですね！

Comment: @nekketsuuu 拡張子だけでいいのですね！教えていただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vetur の [FAQ](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#no-syntax-highlighting--no-language-features-working) に同様の項目があるのを見つけました：

> ### No Syntax Highlighting & No Language Features working
>
> The two possible causes are:
>
> 1. Other extensions also contribute a Vue language, and that conflicts with Vetur.
> 2. VS Code didn't install Vetur properly.
>
> For 1, try disabling all other Vue related extensions.
>
> For 2, try these methods:
>
> - Run command: `Developer: Reinstall Extension` for Vetur.
> - Remove Vetur in your [extensions folder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_common-questions)
>     and do a clean reinstall.
> - (Windows): Try removing & reinstall Vetur with admin privilege.
> - If nothing above works, download the [latest pre-packaged vsix file](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/releases) and [install through
>
>     vsix](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_install-from-a-vsix).

和訳：よくある原因がふたつあります。

1. 他の拡張機能も Vue 用の機能を提供していて、Vetur と干渉している。
2. VS Code が Vetur をきちんとインストールできていない。

1 の場合、まずは他の拡張機能を無効にしてみてください。2の場合、次の手順を試してみてください。

- Vetur の `Developer: Reinstall Extension` コマンドを実行して再インストールする。
- 拡張機能一覧から Vetur を削除し、クリーンな状態から再びインストールする。
- Windows の場合、削除＆再インストールを管理者権限で実行してみる。
- 上のどれも上手く動かなかった場合、vsix の最新版を vsix 経由でインストールする。

※既に vsix 経由でのインストールを試されたとのことですが、念のため回答として投稿してみます。

Comment: いつもご回答いただきありがとうございます！
拡張子を.jsにすることで解決とさせていただきます！

Comment: @Yusuke_O_kaiy 解決してよかったです！　もしそれで解決したのでしたら、こちらの回答とは別の内容となりますので、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)として別に回答を投稿し、そちらを（数時間待って）承認していただけないでしょうか。